# Why is this query slow when restricted to one user id but fast without that?

Tags: mysql, performance, correlated-subquery

When I run this query on a MySQL DB, it returns in 200 ms:

```
SELECT Players.id, Players.level, Players.firstName, Players.lastname, RankedPlayers.rank, Players.points
FROM Players
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
    id,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM Players p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY points DESC
) as RankedPlayers
    ON RankedPlayers.id = Players.id
ORDER BY rank;
```

But when I add in `WHERE player.id = 231145` it takes **9 seconds**!

```
SELECT Players.id, Players.level, Players.firstName, Players.lastname, RankedPlayers.rank, Players.points
FROM Players
INNER JOIN
(
    SELECT
    id,
    @curRank := @curRank + 1 AS rank
    FROM Players p, (SELECT @curRank := 0) r
    ORDER BY points DESC
) as RankedPlayers
    ON RankedPlayers.id = Players.id
WHERE Players.id  = 231145
ORDER BY rank;
```

Comment: Not sure about the performance difference, assuming `Players.id` is indexed; but that subquery is not correlated.

Comment: @Uueerdo `Players.id` is the primary key, and is there a better way to do this query? I need to find the player's rank (and all their friends, so the query will eventually be like:  `WHERE Players.id IN (23123,324523,67123)...`

Comment: Putting the rank subquery into a temp table and indexing it's id may speed up the join, but I am not sure why the WHERE condition is slowing things down; maybe try using [EXPLAIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Comment: @Uueerdo I did but am not sure how to use the info it returns to improve the query

Comment: Use explain on both versions of the query, and add the results to your question. I'm definitely not the best at interpreting it's output, but it might help others help you. _Also, including the CREATE for the table would probably be helpful._

Comment: @jean if I move it to the inner clause, it'll be the wrong rankings. It'll only be a ranking of one user

Comment: @jean yes it is. But it's that player's rank among **all** the players. If you put it on the inner query, the inner query will be  group of 1 and they'll always be ranked #1.

Comment: @DonRhummy I had invited you in a ping to a chat room [Campaigns](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/95290/campaigns) 12 to 14  hours ago to attempt in assisting getting the schema and explains dumped. But it seems a no-show

Comment: @Drew Sorry, I saw "You're invited to Campaigns" and I thought it was a spam advertisement.

Comment: I have never been on a receiving end. Don't blame ya

Comment: Where is the schema in that Campaigns?

Comment: @RickJames we never got to it. He was busy. The transcript reflects that.